# assign attribute value to another attribute on 389-ldap

Tags: ldap

i need to assign the value of an existing attribute to another attribute

i have this attribute "ntUserDomainId" on 389-LDAP and I need it to take its value dynamic from another attribute, for example, this one "sn=amr"

Answer (score 0):

I guess that can be achieve with a server side custom plugin. But otherwise, I don't believe that you can do this out of the box with any LDAP server.

Comment: are there any tool to sync LDAP to an Active directory  because I face issue every time I need to sync LDAP to an AD I need to open each user in LDAP and add the user object and sync again